# Maybe monad in Python with method chaining

Tags: python, exception, monads, method-chaining, option-type

I'm trying to implement the Maybe monad in python. 
However what I also want is some kind of a chaining ability.

So I have a class:

```
class Maybe:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def do(self, func):  # Bind function
        if self.val is None:
            return None
        else:
            return func(self.val)
```

I have two functions :

```
def double(number):
    try:
        result = number * 2
        return Maybe(result)
    except:
        return Maybe(None)

def square(number):
    try:
        result = number * number
        return Maybe(result)
    except:
        return Maybe(None)
```

Here's how I'm using this :

```
 result = Maybe(5).do(double).do(square)
    print(result.val)
```

I'm looking at a way to chain multiple functions each performing a specific task. Each function takes the output of the previous function as input. The chain should break if any function in the chain throws an exception.

Is this the right way to model the Maybe monad ?

Is this the right way to handle exceptions too ?

Can this be improved upon ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is better off on code review, since you're not trying to solve a specific problem and just want some comments on your code.

Comment: Nope, this is not better off, since the code is not working either :D

Comment: Take a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMonad/

Comment: I think this is the context: [Maybe monad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29#The_Maybe_monad)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: It should work now.

Comment: @MarkR. I have had a look at the PyMonad library ..but I don't think I need that level of complexity at this point. I just want to evolve it as needed.

Comment: `Maybe(0).do(double)`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Apologies, corrected the null check.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The downside to this is that it intentionally suppresses errors, which is generally considered a bad idea in python.

However, you can catch and store any errors occur in your `Maybe` instance and report them back.

For example:

```
class Maybe(object):
    def __init__(self, val, error=None):
        self.val = val
        self.error = error

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.val is not None:
            return repr(self.val)
        else:
            return repr(self.error)

    def do(self, func):
        if self.val is None:
            return self
        try:
            return Maybe(func(self.val))
        except Exception as e:
            return Maybe(None, e)

def squared(x):
    return x * x

def addone(x):
    return x + 1

result1 = Maybe(5).do(squared).do(addone)
result2 = Maybe('a').do(squared).do(addone)
print result1
print result2
```

This yields:

```
26
TypeError("can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'",)
```

This is similar to DanD's answer, but has the advantage of storing the error that occurred instead of completely suppressing it.

No matter how you slice it, this idiom is going to feel somewhat "unpythonic", but this is a slightly more robust way of handling it.

Comment: Thanks Joe ... this looks even better... but why would you call this approach 'unpythonic' ?

Comment: Mostly the fact that the error doesn't "propagate" up.  Instead you need to check the value that's returned.  Value-checking in place of try/except is generally considered unpythonic.  It's not necessarily bad, it will just always seem a bit out-of-place.  It's basically the old argument of "look before you leap" vs. "it's easier to ask forgiveness than permission". Python prefers the latter.

Answer (score 6):

The following does what you ask for and lets the functions be a tad bit cleaner. Also updated to capture exceptions properly:

```
class Maybe:
    def __init__(self, val, err=None):
        self.val = val
        self.err = err

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.err is not None:
           return 'Maybe('+repr(self.val)+', '+repr(self.err)+')'
        else:
           return 'Maybe('+repr(self.val)+')'

    def do(self, func):  # Bind function
        if self.val is not None:
            try:
                val = func(self.val)
            except Exception as e:
                return Maybe(None, e)
            if not isinstance(val, Maybe):
                return Maybe(val)
            else:
                 return val
        else:
            return Maybe(None, self.err)


def double(number):
    result = number * 2
    return result

def square(number):
    result = number * number
    return result

result = Maybe(5).do(double).do(square)
print(result.val)
print(result)
result2 = Maybe('a').do(double).do(square)
print(result2.val)
print(result2)
```

Prints:

```
100
Maybe(100)
None
Maybe(None, TypeError("can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'",))
```

Comment: Thanks ... the exception handling in the individual methods was really annoying me. This looks so much better.

Answer (score 4):

I might consider a few adjustments:

- Store the exceptions, as others have suggested.
- Make `Maybe` callable to eliminate the need for `do`.
- Pass `xs` and `kws` through the call, in case any of your functions take other arguments.

For example:

```
class Maybe:
    def __init__(self, val, error = None):
        self.val = val
        self.error = error

    def __call__(self, func, *xs, **kws):
        v = None
        e = None
        if self.val is not None:
            try:
                v = func(self.val, *xs, **kws)
            except Exception as e:
                pass
        return Maybe(v, error = e)

def double(n):
    return n * 2

def square(n):
    return n * n

def multiply_by(n, by):
    return n * by

def message(n, *xs, **kws):
    return 'Message: {} {} {}'.format(n, xs, kws)

ms = [
    Maybe(5)(double)(square),
    Maybe(4)(square)(square)(double),
    Maybe(3)(square)(square),
    Maybe(7)(multiply_by, 3),
    Maybe(9)(message, 1, 2, 3, foo = 'blah'),
    Maybe('hi')(double)(square),
]

for m in ms:
    print(dict(val = m.val, error = m.error))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. I'm spoilt for choice now !

Answer (score 4):

This question has already been answered, but I felt the interface using the Maybe monad could be made more readable. An interface that would allow for a left-right call such as:

```
 square(double(Maybe(5)))
```

Also, it would be nice to return a Maybe type to the user to use so they can choose to further chain rather than immediately retrieve the value. This functionality is similar to Swift's Optional type.

```
class Maybe(object):
  def __init__(self, val=None)
     self.val

  def unwrap(self):
     return self.val

  def calc(self, func):
     try:
       return func(self.val)
     except:
       return None

def double(number):
    return Maybe(maybe.calc(lambda x: x*2))

def square(number):
    return Maybe(maybe.calc(lambda x: x**2))

print square(double(Maybe(5))) # prints Maybe type
print square(double(Maybe(5))).unwrap() # prints '100'
print square(double(None)) # prints 'None'
```

Exceptions are not stored in my answer because the caller expects the [maybe monad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29#The_Maybe_monad) to check the exception itself and convert to "nothing" (i.e. None) if a chained operation fails. This allows the user to handle failures easily in conditionals using chains.